NextJs 14 and useContext throw error even if provider is defined
I been struggle with this silly issue but I can't find the solution:
Context: I'm working in a "global context" in my NextJs 14 app to store some information that need to be consumed by different components. The easy case is a boolean to confirm if a drawer component (MUI) is open or close.
file: app.context.tsx
This is the definition of my context
import React from 'react';

// Define the shape of the context
export type AppContextProps = {
    isDrawerOpen: boolean;
    setIsDrawerOpen: (value: boolean) => void;
};

// Create the context
export const AppContext = React.createContext<AppContextProps | null>(null);

// Create a provider component
export const AppContextProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
    const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

    const context = {
        isDrawerOpen,
        setIsDrawerOpen: (value: boolean) => {
            setIsDrawerOpen(value);
        },
    };

    return <AppContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAppContext = () => {
    const context = React.useContext(AppContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error('useAppContext must be used within a AppContextProvider');
    }
    return context;
};

file: context.layout.tsx
this is the component to wrap the children of the global layout into the AppContextProvider
import { AppContextProvider } from '@/context/app.context';
import { ContextLayoutProps } from './context.interfaces';

const ContextLayout: React.FC<ContextLayoutProps> = ({ children }) => {
    return <AppContextProvider>{children}</AppContextProvider>;
};

export default ContextLayout;

file: global.layout.tsx
This file is where I use the function useAppContext() to detect the changes in the drawer
'use client';
import { useAppContext } from '@/context/app.context';
import { AsetIcon } from '@/icons';
import { HomeWork } from '@mui/icons-material';
import {
    Box,
    Divider,
    Drawer,
    Fab,
    Grid,
    IconButton,
    List,
    ListItem,
    ListItemButton,
    ListItemIcon,
    ListItemText,
    Typography,
    useMediaQuery,
} from '@mui/material';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ContextLayout from '../context/context.layout';
import { GlobalLayoutDrawerItem, GlobalLayoutProps } from './global.interfaces';
import logo from '/public/images/logo-blanco.svg';

const drawerNavigationItems: GlobalLayoutDrawerItem[] = [
    {
        primary: 'Home',
        icon: <HomeWork color="secondary" />,
        href: '/',
    },
];

const GlobalLayout: React.FC<GlobalLayoutProps> = props => {
    const { children } = props;
    const { isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen } = useAppContext();
    const [drawerWidth, setDrawerWidth] = useState<string>('68px');
    const isMobile: boolean = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 600px)');
    const toggleDrawer = () => {
        setIsDrawerOpen(!isDrawerOpen);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isDrawerOpen);
        if (isDrawerOpen) {
            setDrawerWidth('240px');
        } else {
            setDrawerWidth('68px');
        }
    }, [isDrawerOpen]);

    return (
        <ContextLayout>
            <Grid container>
                {isMobile ? (
                    <>
                        <Fab
                            component={'button'}
                            variant="sunset"
                            sx={{
                                position: 'absolute',
                                bottom: 20,
                                right: 20,
                            }}
                            onClick={toggleDrawer}
                        >
                            <AsetIcon />
                        </Fab>
                        {isDrawerOpen ? (
                            <Box>
                                <nav>
                                    <List>
                                        <Divider
                                            component="li"
                                            variant="fullWidth"
                                            sx={{
                                                borderColor: '#F1752F',
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        {drawerNavigationItems.map((item, index) => (
                                            <ListItem disablePadding key={index}>
                                                <ListItemButton href={item.href}>
                                                    {item.icon ? <ListItemIcon children={item.icon} /> : null}
                                                    <ListItemText
                                                        primary={item.primary}
                                                        sx={{
                                                            color: 'white',
                                                        }}
                                                    />
                                                </ListItemButton>
                                            </ListItem>
                                        ))}
                                    </List>
                                </nav>
                            </Box>
                        ) : null}
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <Drawer
                        variant="permanent"
                        color="primary"
                        anchor="left"
                        open={isDrawerOpen}
                        sx={{
                            width: drawerWidth,
                            flexShrink: 0,
                            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
                                width: drawerWidth,
                                boxSizing: 'border-box',
                            },
                        }}
                    >
                        <Box p={0}>
                            <IconButton
                                onClick={toggleDrawer}
                                sx={{
                                    height: '120px',
                                    boxSizing: 'content-box',
                                    paddingBottom: '20px',
                                }}
                            >
                                <Image src={logo} alt="PataSalada" width={36} />
                                {isDrawerOpen ? (
                                    <Typography
                                        variant="h4"
                                        textAlign={'left'}
                                        ml={2}
                                        sx={{
                                            color: 'white',
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        Some text
                                    </Typography>
                                ) : null}
                            </IconButton>
                        </Box>
                        {isDrawerOpen ? (
                            <Box>
                                <nav>
                                    <List>
                                        <Divider
                                            component="li"
                                            variant="fullWidth"
                                            sx={{
                                                borderColor: '#F1752F',
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        {drawerNavigationItems.map((item, index) => (
                                            <ListItem disablePadding key={index}>
                                                <ListItemButton href={item.href}>
                                                    {item.icon ? <ListItemIcon children={item.icon} /> : null}
                                                    <ListItemText
                                                        primary={item.primary}
                                                        sx={{
                                                            color: 'white',
                                                        }}
                                                    />
                                                </ListItemButton>
                                            </ListItem>
                                        ))}
                                    </List>
                                </nav>
                            </Box>
                        ) : null}
                    </Drawer>
                )}
                <Grid
                    item
                    sx={{
                        width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth})`,
                        marginLeft: drawerWidth,
                    }}
                >
                    {children}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ContextLayout>
    );
};

export default GlobalLayout;


The app throws the error in useAppContext because context is null, that means the AppContextProvider is not setting the value in AppContext.Provider usage.
I can't find the reason, I read similar issues but must of them are because use the context wrapper in my case AppContextProvider is not properly defined.
I research about the similar issues and try move the context of the wrapper, move the moment where useAppContext() is called and nothing change.
Expect to consume and set the value of the context effortless for the application to render the right size of the component.
Have any idea, solution or advice?
Thanks in advance.

I believe the problem is that GlobalLayout is trying to use the app context, but the provider is nested inside it rather than wrapped around it, so the context hasn’t been provided yet at the point where it is used. One solution might be to refactor the top levelGrid component and it’s descendants into a separate component (maybe AppCompnent) and move the useContext call there.

I’d love to provide this as a full answer with example code, but the question has many third party dependencies that aren’t essential to the question and make it hard to run the code. Please consider rewriting as a [mre] with only the code that is required to demonstrate the problem, and no external package dependencies.

The problem was in the AppContext, this element was defined in wrong context , once I move it, the issue just gone, thanks guys.
